# Excel VBA Userform Listbox Column Format

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, format

I am populating my list box with a range of numbers (visible numbers only after a filter). I need the column to be formatted as currency ("$#,##0.00).

Any help is great!

I believe I have tried everything but am looking for any possible suggestions.

```
    Dim rngSize As Range
    Set rngSize = ws1.Range("O12:O" & LR1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    With frmReportEnd.lbSize
        For Each Cell In rngSize
          .ColumnCount = 1
          .ColumnWidths = "100"

          .AddItem Cell.Value
          .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Format(rngSize)
        Next Cell
    End With
```

Comment: Which column do you want formatted? And what's `frmReportEnd.lbSize`?

Comment: It would be the first column in the list box and frmReportEnd.lbSize is the Userform2.ListBox

Comment: OK, why do you do this repeatedly: `.ColumnCount = 1
          .ColumnWidths = "100"` Can't it be done before the `For` loop?

Comment: Maybe `.AddItem Format(Cell.Value, "$#,##0.00")`

Comment: Yeah I can put it before the For loop. But it still does not solve the formatting problem

Comment: .AddItem Format(Cell.Value, "$#,##0.00")...worked. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim rngSize As Range
    Set rngSize = ws1.Range("O12:O" & LR1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    With frmReportEnd.lbSize
        .ColumnCount = 1
        .ColumnWidths = "100"
        For Each Cell In rngSize
           .AddItem Format(Cell.Value, "$#,##0.00")
          .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Format(rngSize)
        Next Cell
    End With
```

Comment: *Friendly hint :-)@AAA - It's unclear why OP assigns a second column (column index **1**) via `.List(.ListCount - 1, 1)` if `ColumnCount` is restricted to a single column. Furthermore I doubt that  `Format` is used correctly if referring to a multicell range whereas a single cell range reference would be transformed internally to its cell value.